# Proving a metric and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be the set of all continuous functions from $[0, 1]$ into $\mathbb R$. For $f, g \in X$, define
> $$d_{1}(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - g(x)| \mathrm dx$$
> and $$d_{2}(f,g) = {\sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]}} |f(x) - g(x)|$$
>
> 1. Prove $d_1$ and $d_{2}$ is a metric.
> 2. Is continuity needed and why?

So I have proved all the conditions that satisfy a metric for $d$ except for, $d(f,g)=0$ if and only if $f=g$. I know that if $f=g$ then $\int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - g(x)| \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{1} |0| \mathrm dx = 0$, so that way is clear the me. And same for $d_{2}$. I am having trouble proving the other way and why continuity is needed for both $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$. I know it is needed, just not sure why.

Comment: (2) Continuity is needed. If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, $g(x)=0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$ then $\int_0^{1} |f(x)-g(x)|dx=0$ but $f \neq g$.

Comment: (1) has appeared many times on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\ne g$ then there exists $x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)\ne g(x)$. Then $\varepsilon=|f(x)-g(x)|>0$. Then we immediately have $d_2(f,g)\ge |f(x)-g(x)|>0$. Since both functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$, there exists $0<\delta\le 1$ such that $|f(x’)-f(x)|\le\varepsilon/3 $ and $|g(x’)-g(x)|\le\varepsilon/3 $ for each $x’\in X$, where $X=\{x\in [0,1]: |x-x’|\le\delta\}$.
Then $$\varepsilon=|f(x)-g(x)|\le |f(x)-f(x’)|+|f(x’)-g(x’)|+|g(x’)-g(x)|\le \varepsilon/3+|f(x’)-g(x’)|+ \varepsilon/3,$$
so $|f(x’)-g(x’)|\ge \varepsilon/3$.
It is easy to see that $X$ is a segment of length $l(X)\ge\delta>0$. Therefore
$$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(t)-g(t)|dt\ge \int_X |f(t)-g(t)|dt \ge \int_X \varepsilon/3 dt= l(X) \varepsilon/3>0.$$